# UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString not work in iOS 10

Tags: ios, settings, ios10

In **iOS 10**, do not open settings url:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did like that and it's works. I'm test it today!

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Swift 3:

```
let urlObj = NSURL.init(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(urlObj as! URL, options: [ : ], completionHandler: { Success in

     })
} else {
      let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
      print("Open \(url): \(success)")                            
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Just in the program did not have the settings and opens the desktop.

Comment: It just opens the empty grey screen with no 'full access switch'

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4

```
if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      _ =  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Apple Swift version 5.3:**

```
  if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),  UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
         UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11 +

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }
}];
```